# htaccess rewrite for https

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Given this rule (that strips www from urls for http):

```
< IfModule mod_rewrite.c >
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</ IfModule >
```

how do I configure the rewrite to work for https as well?

Answer (score 0):

A simple search [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192948/remove-www-site-wide-force-https-on-certain-directories-and-http-on-the-rest):

```
# remove www from host
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s/%1 ^(on(s)|offs)/(.+)
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%3%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Note: the `[L]` directive may be redundant in your case if it's not the [L]ast rule applied...