# redirect clients connecting via "www.domain.com" to "domain.com" using django

Tags: django

it seems like google links to my page contain a "www." before the domain, this causes security errors since I'm reading data from the canvas and the images will be marked as cross-orign if they are from "www.x.com" rather than "x.com".

So i'm wondering what's the nicest way to redirect people from the url with the www. in it to one without?

(alternately, can I get google to link without the www?)

Thanks

Comment: For Google part, check the pages indexed by Google, they should be in the form of `domain.com/...` instead if `www.domain.com/...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be to let your webserver (apache/nginx) handle the redirect, instead of doing it in Django.

In nginx it could look something like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;
        rewrite ^(.*) http://example.com:80$1 permanent;
}
```

Of course you could do it in Django, simply check for the existence of the subdomain `www` and then redirect to the same URL without this subdomain. In this case you would need to add this logic to all of your views though (could be a decorator for example). Still, its hard to maintain and the better and simpler approach is the one I mentioned above.

Comment: +1 agreed. The place for this is at the front end proxy/web server and not in the app.

Comment: I also agree with @BurhanKhalid. But if you do it in your Django code, don't use view decorators, use a middleware instead. That's where code belongs that should be executed for *all* requests.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. My webhost uses apache so I found this to be useful [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192948/remove-www-site-wide-force-https-on-certain-directories-and-http-on-the-rest)