# .htaccess force https on certain urls otherwise force http

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, ssl

I'm trying to force SSL on 3 pages of a website, and force the rest to http

mydomain.com/register , mydomain.com/checkout and mydomain.com/thanks all need to redirect to https: but any other page should just use http:

Is this possible?

I currently have some codeigniter specific stuff in my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Probably duplicate - see for example these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192948/remove-www-site-wide-force-https-on-certain-directories-and-http-on-the-rest

Comment: It is not duplicate, question is right. Need to find the solution for CodeIgniter.... For CI it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Not a .htaccess solution, but here's how I force https connections:

```
// Redirect to secure port
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443)
{
    $location = 'Location: https://www.blah.com';
    header($location);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you are using apache, you should have access to many SSL-related variables, in PHP they will be visible under `$_SERVER[]`. Here is list http://www.modssl.org/docs/2.8/ssl_reference.html#ToC25

Answer (score 2):

I think this code will work (specially for CodIgniter)

```
RewriteEngine on

# force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (register|checkout|thanks)
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(register|checkout|thanks|css|img|js)
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L]
```